# RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage" with solana program

Tags: solana-program, build-bpf, rustc

Trying to add check coverage, when using `RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage" cargo build-bpf` I'm getting:

```
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -C instrument-coverage -Zremap-cwd-prefix= --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  error: unknown codegen option: `instrument-coverage`
```

Regular `cargo build` works, so it seems to be directly related to the `solana` target.